# Separate Mod_Rewrite rules

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Simple question that I'm stuck on:

I'm working on a Wordpress installation and added a few `mod_rewrite` rules to work around some pretty URLs and staging content. It works, it's great.

**When I separate the rules out into their own modules to avoid overwriting by the WP system on permalink changes they stop working**. Syntax error that I don't understand?

This works:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  # BEGIN My additions

    # Nice URLs
      RewriteRule ^assets/(.*) /wp-content/themes/cool-theme/assets/$1 [QSA,L]
      RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]

    # Staging media
      RewriteRule ^media/(.*) http://coolsite.com/media/$1 [P]

  # END My additions

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This doesn't:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN Cool Theme

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule ^assets/(.*) /wp-content/themes/cool-theme/assets/$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>

# END Cool Theme

# BEGIN Cool Site Staging

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule ^media/(.*) http://coolsite.com/media/$1 [P]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>

# END Cool Site Staging
```

Comment: Since WP is writing everything to `index.php` your rules below won't see `REQUEST_URI` as the original URI.

Comment: @anubhava got it. Given that the WP block should be seen as impermanent... what do you recommend? Moving them before the WP block would get overwritten, right?

Comment: @anubhava right, but that block gets rewritten on permalink changes and cache updates, losing any modifications that have been made -- so it's fine short term but won't work long term.